# OS X Automator Shell-script workflow window enter filename

Tags: shell, popupwindow, automator

I have an Automator workflow with a shell- script that lets me
choose this Service in eg. Safari web browser to convert an Weburl to PDF with the use of wkhtmltopdf.

wkhtmltopdf is installed at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.

**Is there a way in Automator to have a Popup-window to enter the name of the destination - file - name (xxxxxx.pdf) ?
How can this be done?**

What i have so far is :

[image: automator_screenshot]

```
for f in "$@"

do

  b=${f##*//}
  s=${b%.*}
 
  /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf "$f" $HOME/Desktop/"$s".pdf

done
```

Answer (score 0):

after digging deeper for several hours i got it working:

- Service receives "Urls" in every Program
- Set Value of Variable -> Variable: [Var1]
- Run Apple Script:
  set resultFile to POSIX path of (choose file name
  with prompt "Save as" default name "MyFile" default location path to
  desktop)
  if resultFile does not end with ".pdf" then set resultFile
  to resultFile & ".pdf"   return resultFile
- Set Value of Variable -> Variable: [Var2]
- Get Value of Variable -> Variable: [Var1] , Options -> [√] Ignore
  this action's input
- Get Value of Variable -> Variable: [Var2]
- run Shell Script -> Shell: [/bin/bash], Pass input: [as arguments]:

  /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf "$1" "$2"